# Want to create a bookmark button for my web browser control for windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to create a bookmark button so that the user can have a bookmark of a web page???
My web browser control for my windows phone 7 application is "browsers". Thanks in advance for your hard work!!!

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Are you talking about general usage of the phone, or creating a button inside an application to perform the "pin to start" functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a standard `Button` control that is able to retrieve the currently opened Url in the `WebBrowser` and either serialize the data to a custom model or simply store the string in the Isolated Storage.

You might want to take a look at [Isolated Storage Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to get an idea how to store the links.